# Django One-to-One field is not saving (violates not-null constraint)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, one-to-one

I'm trying to save a form that has a one-to-one field.

However it keep getting an error *null value in column "account_id" violates not-null constraint*.

Not sure why I couldn't save the new account object in the one-to-one field.

Model:

```py
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Bank(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(
        Account, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        primary_key=True
    )
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

View:

```py
def add_bank_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BankForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            account = Account.objects.create(name='xxx')
            bankform = form.save(commit=False)
            bankform.account = account
            bankform.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/add_banks/')
    else:
        form = BankForm()
    return render(request, 'bank/add_bank.html', {'form': form})
```

Form:

```py
class BankForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Bank
    fields = ['bank_name']
```

Comment: does the account object has a pk on this point? can you print account.pk and get a result before the assignment? your database engine could be acting funny around transactions.

Comment: `account = Account.objects.create(bank_name='xxx') ` can you try this

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help.

I found that it is impossible to use ModelForm in the case of an One-to-One field if the Account field is not yet set. A solution is to use the basic Form, then set both Account and Bank record in your views using the data from the basic Form.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below with [models.OneToOneField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield):

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "person_id" of
> relation "my_app_persondetail" violates not-null constraint

Because I didn't set [null=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#null) when setting [blank=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#blank) to `models.OneToOneField()`, then tried to add the blank data `---------` on **Add** page in Django Admin as shown below. *For `models.OneToOneField()` and [models.ForeignKey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) in Django, we need to set `null=True` when setting `blank=True`:

```py
# "my_app/models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class PersonDetail(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        Person, 
        blank=True, # Here
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

[image]

So, I set `null=True` with `blank=True` to `models.OneToOneField()` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
# "my_app/models.py"

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class PersonDetail(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        Person, 
        blank=True, 
        null=True, # Here
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```